# Convert ArrayList of String from Retrofit response

Tags: android, json, arraylist, retrofit2

I want to convert this json response `["tunisie","canada"]`to a List to be able to use it in a Spinner.
this is my retrofit call:

```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   public void populatePays(){
   pays = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pays_spinner);
   pays.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   apiService = RestService.createService(SolarAPIService.class);
   Call<ArrayList<String>> call = apiService.listPays();
   call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {
          list.addAll(response.body());

       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Throwable t) {

       }
   });
   ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
           (this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
           (R.layout.spinner_drop_down_item);
   pays.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

  }
```

after the execution I end up with an empty Spinner. So apperentaly my response is not being converted to my `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting values to adapter is happening on the main thread, but the api call response is going through another thread, you should call

`dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

just after the

`list.addAll(response.body());`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
           (this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
           (R.layout.spinner_drop_down_item);
   pays.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

inside:

```
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {
          list.addAll(response.body());
          // HERE
       }
```

Comment: try to log the response

Comment: I changed this to `getApplication()`